# Add/Delete row dynamically to/from jquery table using angularjs not working properly

Tags: html, angularjs

```
futureMakerApp.controller('EmailTemplateController', function($scope, $location, $http, $cookieStore, CONSTANTS, userService) {
      $scope.templates = [{
        'no': 1,
        'name': 'Template1',
        'Dates': '11/10/2015'
      }, {
        'no': 2,
        'name': 'Template2',
        'Dates': '11/11/2015'
      }, {
        'no': 3,
        'name': 'Template3',
        'Dates': '11/12/2015'
      }, ];


      //Function to add rows to table

      $scope.addRow = function() {
        $scope.templates.push({
          'no': $scope.no,
          'name': $scope.name,
          'Dates': $scope.Dates
        });
        $scope.no = '';
        $scope.name = '';
        $scope.Dates = '';
      };

      // Function to delete row from table
      //while inspecting following code using breakpoints it is saying name=undefined
      $scope.removeRow = function(name) {
        var index = $scope.templates.indexOf(name);
        //var index = -1;       
        //var comArr = eval( $scope.templates );
        //for( var i = 0; i < comArr.length; i++ ) {
        //  if( comArr[i].name === name ) {
        //      index = i;
        //      break;
        //  }
        //}
        //if( index === -1 ) {
        //  alert( "Something went wrong!!!" );
        //}
        $scope.templates.splice(index, 1);
      };

    });
```

Comment: can you add your html code?

Comment: please find the html code in comments below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your code to create some test [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/51bsbzL0/13/).
I simplified it a bit and it work fine.

HTML:

```
<div id="body">
  <div ng-controller="EmailTemplateController">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>no</th>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>Dates</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="template in templates">
          <td>{{template.no}}</td>
          <td>{{template.name}}</td>
          <td>{{template.Dates}}</td>
          <td><button ng-click="removeRow(template)">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
controller('EmailTemplateController', function($scope) {
      $scope.templates = [{
        'no': 1,
        'name': 'Template1',
        'Dates': '11/10/2015'
      }, {
        'no': 2,
        'name': 'Template2',
        'Dates': '11/11/2015'
      }, {
        'no': 3,
        'name': 'Template3',
        'Dates': '11/12/2015'
      }, ];

      $scope.removeRow = function(name) {
        var index = $scope.templates.indexOf(name);
        $scope.templates.splice(index, 1);
      };

    });
```

It looks like you created removeRow function to handle the clicks on the button, but you used this function in a wrong way, because it expected the paramerer - the item that needs to be removed.

Hope it will help.

Comment: After refreshing the webpage, the deleted entry is reappearing and also, after deletion it is not reflecting the proper values in table length (i.e.-it is showing "show 1 to 3 of 3 entries" even after deletion of row. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Can anyone please help with the issue mentioned in above comment?

Comment: How do you display your table length?

Comment: I am using bootstrap table.

<div id="bootstrap-table_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer"><div class="dataTables_length" id="bootstrap-table_length"><label>Show <select name="bootstrap-table_length" aria-controls="bootstrap-table" class=""><option value="10">10</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option></select> entries</label>
<div class="dataTables_info" id="bootstrap-table_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 4 of 4 entries</div>

Answer (score 0):

```
 //please find the html code below

   <div ng-controller="EmailTemplateController">

    <div class="section">
        <div class="left-section left-section-inner">
            <div class="bs-example">




                            <div class="acc-tables">
                                <h2>Email Templates <!-- <span class="close">X</span><a class="view-all-candi" href="">View All Candidates</a>--></h2>

                                <div class="bottom-btns">
                                    <a class="approve" href="/html/#/home/email-template/write-template">Write New Template</a>
                                </div>




                                <table class="table datatable table-hover table-striped" id="bootstrap-table">
                                    <thead>


                                    <tr>
                                        <th>no</th>
                                        <th>name</th>
                                        <th>Dates</th>
                                        <th>Actions</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>

                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>

                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td><a href="">Template1<a></td>
                                        <td>11/10/2015</td>

                                        <td>
                                            <a href=""><img src="images/edit-icon.png"></a>
                                            <a href=""><img src="images/msg-icon.png"></a>
                                            <!--<a href=""><img class="delete" src="images/del-icon.png" ng-click="removeRow(template.name);" />-->
                                            <a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-ng-click="removeRow()">Delete</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    </tbody>

                                </table>
                                <div class="bottom-btns">

                                    <a class="uncheck-all" href="/html/#/home">Close</a>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                </div>          

            </div>
        </div>
```